# Can I allow an item to be rendered upon public request from a website, but not viewable directly in browser?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Forgive me if this has already been well documented... but I have spent  quite some time searching the relevant Google Cloud Storage help/documentation pages, and looking through old posts on here... and I can't seem to find what I'm after.

My question is as follow:

I am using GCS to host a website. So far so good. Everything works as it should.

But, is it possible to allow items (images or a .css file, for example) stored in a GCS bucket to be called by a page (index.html for example) but not be visible directly in a browser when the URL of the time is visited?

So for example:

• I want index.html (which is publicly viewable) to be able to make use of main.css for rendering, and display logo.png

• but I don't want someone to be able to see the css by going to http://www.website.com/main.css and I don't want them to be able to load the logo by going to http://www.website.com/logo.png

I hope that make sense?

Is this possible? If so, I assume the way I'm trying to do it (below) is wrong!

Thank you!

I've tried using "per item" permissions and making only "index.html" public, and everything else viewable by Domain: "website.com" (I assume this allows view requests originating from pages on that Domain (i.e. my index.html page) to see the files. This didn't work.

I tried "entire bucket" permissions method and left index.html in the bucket designated to www.website.com but moved the images and css files into another bucket. I then set the website bucket to be publicly viewable, and the new bucket with the images and css to be visible by website.com. This didn't work either.

I don't think I can do it with .htaccess, as I GCS doesn't support that... right?

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to prevent users from seeing resources that their browser can request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible to prevent users from seeing resources that their browser can request.